# PHPStorm 8.0.3 Rest client not appending request parameters in POST request

Tags: rest, http, phpstorm

Like the title says I think I have a problem with the "Test RESTful web service" client. When I make a GET request, the request parameters, for example ?test=1&b=2 would be added. When I make a POST request, they are not added anymore.

Is this normal behaviour, or a bug in the client? And is allowing the request parameters when using a POST method a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue, please vote for [WEB-10584](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10584)